# jplayer html5 help amazon s3 not streaming in firefox and ie but works in chrome

Tags: cross-browser, amazon-s3, jplayer

I am so close to setting up jplayer html5 with Amazon s3 its frustrating.

http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demos/

It works fine in chrome no problem at all but struggles to work in firefox and ie safari, this is a problem with my code as your demos provided work with no problem at all.

So i have debugged and debugged and i am down to thinking it is just the urls.

Here is a file from my amazon s3 account

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdmusic/Music/dnb/Rescue+Me+(Sigma+Mix)_Skepta_192.mp3
```

And here is theirs

```
http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-02-Hidden.mp3
```

I can play both these in the browser and they work fine.

any help please here is my demo.

http://isdplugins.users34.interdns.co.uk/

its not streaming in firefox and ie but works in chrome

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with the spaces percent-encoded

```
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/isdmusic/Music/dnb/Rescue%20Me%20(Sigma%20Mix)_Skepta_192.mp3
```